# Reading multiple files in a for loop in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am reading several files located in `paths.lst` file to change/remove some content of them.

```
C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml
C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml
C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml
```

```bash
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%i in (paths.lst) do (
    call :$change %%i
)
pause

:$change
if exist "%~1" (
    set filePath='%1'
    echo Value changed for:'%filePath%'
    set "fold='<XMLElement>To ;Value</XMLElement>'"
    set fnew=''
    powershell -Command "(gc %filePath%) -replace %fold%, %fnew% | Out-File %filePath% -encoding ascii"
) else (
    echo File does not exist:'%~1'
)
```

I want to get rid of the `paths.lst` file and integrate the file paths into the script. For this I assign a variable to each path and try to read all of them in a `for` loop. But it reads only the first file, not the rest.

```bash
set file1="C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml"
set file2="C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml"
set file3="C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml"   

for /f "delims=" %%i (%file1% %file2% %file3%) do (
    call :$change"%%i"
)
pause
```

**EDIT:**
I have applied the variante from @mklement0. It seems I have still issue with the `if else` condition. Since it does not goes through the whole list:

```
In Line:1 Character:17
+ (gc ) -replace , | Out-File -encoding ascii
+ ~
Expression missing after unary operator ",".
     + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Value changed for:''
Value changed for:''C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml''
Press any key . . .


set filePath="C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml" ^
             "C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml" 

for %%i in (%filePath%) do (
    call :$change %%i
)
pause

exit/b 0

:$change 
if exist "%~1" (
    set filePath= '%~1'
    set "fold='<XMLElement>To ;Value</XMLElement>'"
    set fnew=''
    powershell -NoProfile -Command "(gc %filePath%) -replace %fold%, %fnew% | Out-File %filePath% -encoding ascii"
    echo Value changed for:'%filePath%'
) else (
    echo File does not exist:'%~1'
)
```

Comment: Can you show your paths.lst file format? I mean, are paths separated by commas? Or by newlines (one name per line)? Or by spaces?

Comment: It is a `LST-File` the separation between the paths are done over newlines.

Comment: In your first example `)else(` is invalid; it should be `) else (`, and could be `)else (`. In the second example `for /f "delims=" %%i (%file1% %file2% %file3%) do (` should be `for %%i (%file1% %file2% %file3%) do (`.

Comment: Also immediately after the `pause` line you need a `GoTo :EOF` or `Exit /B` line

Comment: Good points, @Compo. Since the `)else(` syntax problem is incidental to what the question is about (which I know your comment addresses too), I've edited the question to fix it.

Comment: @mystic.06 Let's summarize: The answer to your original question is: remove `/f "delims="` from your `for` statement, and it will work.
You've now edited your question to ask about a _follow-up_ problem that is unrelated
to your original question. My updated answer now address that problem too, but in the future, please don't do that: Instead, if appropriate, accept an answer that addresses your question _as asked_ and then create  a _new_ question post focused just on the follow-up problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- The next section addresses your question as asked.
- The bottom section addresses an incidental, unrelated problem with your code.

---

**Use `for` *without options***; that is, remove `/f "delims="`:

```
for %%i in (%file1% %file2% %file3%) do call :$change %%i
```

- `for` without options iterates over the elements of a space-separated list while recognizing double-quoted elements as such and *retaining* the double quotes.

  - `,` and `;` work as the list separator too.
  - By contrast, the purpose of `for /f` is to either read *the contents of* a given file or the *output from a command*, line by line (omitting blank lines).
- While this iteration works for list of strings in general, note that elements with *wildcard* characters (`*`, `?`), whether double-quoted or not, are *invariably* interpreted as file-name *patterns* and are replaced with the names or paths (as specified) of matching files, if any.<sup>[1]</sup>
  To match *directories* instead, use the `/D` option.
- Run `for /?` for help

---

Note that you don't need *individual* variables and can instead **store the list in a *single* variable**:

```
set files="C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml" "C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml" "C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml"
for %%i in (%files%) do call :$change %%i
```

To make this more maintainable and readable, you **can spread the list definition across *multiple lines*, using `^`** for *line continuation*:

```
:: IMPORTANT:
::   All lines but the last must end in ^
::   All lines but the first must *start with whitespace*
set files="C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml" ^
          "C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir2}\test.xml" ^
          "C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml"

for %%i in (%files%) do call :$change %%i
```

---

The ***incidental* problem** with your code:

- **Inside a given `(...)` enclosure, variables defined therein (with `set`) are *not* visible to the commands in the same enclosure**.

  - Therefore, your `powershell` command didn't see the `%fold%`, `%fnew%` and `%filePath%` values you defined. (Because `%filePath%` was previously defined *outside* `(...)` its *original* value is seen inside).
- **Restructure your code to avoid use of `(...)`**, as follows:

```
@echo off & setlocal

set filePaths="C:\Users\ect\doc doc\test dir\conf\{testdir1}\test.xml" ^
             "C:\Users\ect\docdoc\testdir\conf\{testdir3}\test.xml" ^
             t.txt

for %%i in (%filePaths%) do call :$change %%i

pause
exit /b 0

:$change 
    if not exist %1 echo File does not exist: %1 & goto :EOF
    :: Getting here means that the file exists
    set filePath='%~1'
    set "fold='<XMLElement>To ;Value</XMLElement>'"
    set fnew=''
    de powershell -NoProfile -Command "(gc %filePath%) -replace %fold%, %fnew% | Out-File %filePath% -encoding ascii"
    echo Value changed for: %filePath%
goto :EOF
```

---

<sup>[1] Trying to use `^` for suppressing the wildcard pattern matching does *not* work, neither does double-quoting. In effect this means that strings that happen to contain `*` or `?` but aren't meant to be file-name patterns cannot be used - they'll either expand to unwanted matches or, more likely, if there are none, be removed altogether.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "file1=file1"
set "file2=file2"
set "file3=file3"

for %%i in (%file1%,%file2%,%file3%) do (
    call :change "%%i"
)
pause


exit/b 0

:change
echo.%*
echo.
:: do your processing here...
```

Or if you want to keep a single variable:

```
@echo off
set files="file1","file with spaces","C:\Path\To\Some Random\File"

for %%i in (%files%) do (
    call :change %%i
)
pause


exit/b 0

:change
echo.%*
echo.
:: do your processing here...
```